# Symmetric algorithm to convert integer ID to String

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

**I want to introduce short uniq string ID using integer from MySQL table field (question_id) with Auto Incr.**

**Example** When user will point to www.something.com/SjBWY -> php will fetch record with id=23511;

I want to hide information about number of questions and introduce question_code which will be mapped 1 to 1 to question_id using some kind of translation algorithm.
I don't want to store question_code in database, I believe MySQL developers are smarter than me and have created reliable mechanism to generate uniq numbers.

**Naive approach:** ( http://ideone.com/rK4hzx )

```
$num = 11231;

while($num > 0) {
    $v = ord( $num % 10);
    $v += 25;
    echo chr($v);

    $num = round($num / 10);
}
// JLKJJ

$result = array_reverse(str_split('JLKJJ'));
foreach ($result as $single) {
 echo chr(ord( $single)-25);
}
// 11231
```

**Question:** Could you suggest better solutions?

Naive aproche weakness:

- I want to be able to use small and large letters
- I want to be able to limit string length to 5 as long as possible.
- In generated string should not be obvious a sequence. Value of 11 should be as far possible from 12.

**EDIT**
Algorithm should be symmetric means I could translate Int->String and String->Int.
MD5 and other hash algorithms are only *one way*, I'm not able to translate from String->Int

Comment: Why not just using a decent hashing algorithm like MD5?

Comment: Use a hashing algorithm to map labels to short strings, and (if you wish) interpret the bytes in the strings as integers

Comment: Hashing will probably be the better option...

Comment: Hashing is one way only.

Comment: @IgorS. It would be pretty easy just to map every letter to its ascii code and concatenate those, then you go could back and forth easily.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yes, this is naive approach included to question. I'm looking for something more flexible.

Comment: @IgorS. You should consider an encryption algorithm also. DES is a pretty simple one. but it will produce a much longer string than you want.

Comment: If the algorithm can convert 2 way Int <-> String, then you're not really hiding any information --- against a more seriously hacking user anyway.

Comment: And you want the string length to be 5; it would help to know how many different IDs you expect to have as input.

Comment: @Billiska it's not hiding from hackers. It's marketing thing, users don't need to know how many other users there are.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found what I was looking for. It's called:
http://www.hashids.org/ it has versions for php, java,nodejs,ruby,.net, etc.

> Hashids was designed for use in URL shortening, tracking stuff,
>   validating accounts or making pages private (through abstraction).
>   Instead of showing items as 1, 2, or 3, you could show them as
>   b9iLXiAa, EATedTBy, and Aaco9cy5. Hashes depend on your salt value.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing isn't a good option, due to the potential for collisions. What you need a bijective transform.

For instance, you could encrypt the ID...

Optionally, base64-encode the resulting bit string, or something to that effect using 6-bit chunks and a character map (e.g. [a-zA-Z0-9_-]).

Whatever you do, make sure you can do the reverse transform reasonably easily.

Answer (score 0):

why not taking the uniq string ID convert it to bytes and then to long/int ? 
To convert back to do convert the long/int to bytes and then to string....